# The PDF of $X^3$ where $ X \sim \text{Normal}(0, 1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning

I have been stumped for a few days on this...It would be great if anyone can point me to enlightenment :)

Here's what I have tried. Let $Y = X^3$, where X is a standard normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1. Then

$P(Y \leq y) = P(X^3 \leq y) = P(X \leq y^{1/3})$, for both $y$ positive or negative.

The above is the CDF of $X^3$; differentiating w.r.t. to $y$ should give me the PDF, which is

$f_X(y^{1/3})\frac{1}{3}y^{-2/3}$, where $f_X$ is the PDF of the standard normal.

---

But THAT cannot be the answer, because it would take on negative values for $y < 0$. Whereas a PDF should always be non-negative. I have seen a "correct" answer in a math paper, where it changes $y$ to $|y|$ and results in an integral that converges (in Mathematica).

But where can I introduce the absolute terms!? Much thanks :D

Comment: The derivative of $g:y\mapsto y^{1/3}$ is positive at every $y\ne0$, in particular, if $y<0$, $$g'(y)=\frac1{3|y|^{2/3}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to find the $|y|$-based formula the first time, rather than saying, "Oh gee, it looks like that needs a little something" near the end. Since $X$'s pdf is even, $Y$'s should be even too. Let $\Phi,\,\phi$ denote the CDF and PDF of $X$. For $y\ge 0$, $$P(Y\le y)=\Phi(y^{1/3})\implies f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{3}y^{-2/3}\phi(y^{1/3}).$$Then, for arbitrary $y\in\mathbb{R}$,$$f_Y(y)=f_Y(|y|)=\frac{1}{3}|y|^{-2/3}\phi(|y|^{1/3}).$$

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see this ... Thank you J.G.!

Answer (score 0):

If $y \ne 0$, the $2$ in the index would make it positive,

$$f_X(y^{1/3})\frac{1}{3}y^{-2/3}=f_X(y^{1/3})\frac{1}{3}y^{-\color{red}2/3} $$

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense...which makes me even more confused. Can you explain why in this paper they introduced an absolute sign? Seems superfluous ...https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176991795

Comment: The problem is that sometimes you might say $(-8)^{-2/3}$ is $-\frac14$ and sometimes $-\frac18 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}i$.  [Wolfram Alpha gives the complex answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-8)%5E(-2%2F3))

Comment: thanks for the enlightenment. I interpreted it as always taking the real root previously.

Comment: Thank you Henry! That's exactly the problem with using Mathematica :)